# Are font family names which contain hyphens identical to the same font names with spaces instead of hyphens?

Tags: css, fonts

After poking around many stylesheets for different websites, I have consistently noticed font or font-family values that are used which do not appear to use correct font-family names. I am wondering if I just don't fully understand how to reference font family names as used by CSS.

For example, on [this stylesheet](http://theweek.com/css/f0d962f.css), the authors use the following several times:

```
font-family:"minion-pro";
```

however, as far as Google tells me, no such font family actually exists. For example, if you Google the following:

```
font minion-pro
```

none of the first several hits show anything "minion-pro", but rather all the hits are for "Minion" or "Minion Pro"; the fifth hit is for [this link](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/minion/), which as far as I understand CSS, requires the user to reference this font as

```
font-family: "Minion Pro";
```

I have also seen this on some stylesheets for the font "Myriad Pro" which, when you Google `font myriad-pro`, only return hits for the font "Myriad" and "Myriad Pro". That is, in CSS stylesheets, I have seen this

```
font-family: "Myriad-Pro";
```

but to me, this is not correct, and should be

```
font-family: "Myriad Pro";
```

So my simple question is: *are fonts which contain spaces able to be rendered properly if the spaces are replaced with hyphens?*

I believe the answer to this is "no" based on the docs - I cannot easily test this because I do not have easy access to these fonts and I am at work right now. (when I try Codepenning this with "Myriad Pro" or "Minion Pro" nothing happens - fonts not recognized)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you name the font-family when you create the `@font-face` font definition to serve your font.

Like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'montserratregular';
    src: url('/content/fonts/Montserrat/montserrat-regular.eot');
    src: url('/content/fonts/Montserrat/montserrat-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/content/fonts/Montserrat/montserrat-regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('/content/fonts/Montserrat/montserrat-regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/content/fonts/Montserrat/montserrat-regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

In this case I would reference `font-family: 'montserratregular';` in my css. But if in the `@font-face` declaration I defined `font-family: 'montserrat-regular';` or `font-family: 'montserrat regular';` then I would use that in my css.

In the stylesheet you linked the author probably has his `@font-face` declarations in a separate css file where he defines Minion Pro as "minion-pro", this is common.

Other fonts that you don't serve to the client, System Fonts, should be referenced by their system font name. You can use a site like [CSS Font Stack](http://www.cssfontstack.com/) to see what those names are and the likelihood (in %) that they are a system font on Windows or Mac. It also provides common fallbacks for fonts (i.e. you could do this: `font-family: 'Myriad Pro', 'Myriad-Pro', 'MyriadPro', Arial;`).

A font like Myriad Pro or Minion Pro don't usually ship as an installed system font by default, so thats why we serve the font to the client using the `@font-face` approach. I user could install Myraid Pro on their machine and then it would be a system font, but you would have to know the exact name and you can't guarantee a user has a unique font or require users who visit your site to manually install it.

Comment: Great explanation - thanks for taking the time to answer in detail